# Python-Django: Cannot find template

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I am new to Python and Django and have been trying to learn how to make a registration form for my website. I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tam4IGrPESg. I have everything working up to the point of the registration_success page. Here is what I think is the relevant code:

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH + '/templates/',
    TEMPLATE_PATH + '/templates/registration',
)
```

urls.py

```
#registration
(r'^register/$', register_user),
(r'^registration_success/$', registration_success),
```

views.py

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('registration_success')         
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    print (args)
    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html',args)

def registration_success(request):
    return render_to_response('registration_success.html')
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/register/registration_success
Using the URLconf defined in tut_1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
^login/$
^logout/$
^register/$
^registration_success/$
^portal/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, registration/registration_success, didn't match any of these.
```

I am not sure exactly what is going on tbh. What I did notice was that the URL is: http: / / localhost:8000/register/registration_success. Why is it register/registration_...? Should it not be registration/registration_success?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error is not that it can't find the template, but that it can't find the page you've requested: ie your URLs don't match. The message is quite clear and doesn't mention templates once.

Answer (score 0):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('registration_success')
```

You are redirecting to a path that is relative to the current url. That explains why you are being routed to /register/registration_success.

To solve this, you need to use a root-relative path

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/registration_success/')
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I attempted your suggestion but I just ended up getting a loop. Correct me if I'm wrong /registration_success/ will call the registration_success function and repeat the loop? I honestly don't know what I did but I did not change any of the code I posted and now it works... unfortunately I cannot say what I did...